# Existence of a chain map

Tags: homological-algebra, diagram-chasing

Let $A$ be a module, $P$ be a chain complex of projective modules, $Q$ its subcomplex. Moreover, let $C$ be a resolution of the chain complex $A[0]$ (that is $(A[0])_0=A$ and $(A[0])_n=0$ otherwise; also we have a quasi-isomorphism $C\xrightarrow\sim A[0]$).

Given the following diagram

[image]

why is there a chain map $P\to C$ (such that the diagram commutes)?

I can handle situations if I have only triangles, but I don't see how to make the whole diagram to commute...

Comment: That's not true in general. 

Take for instance $A= 0, P,Q,C= \mathbb Z[0]$ and the inclusion $Q\to P$ is multiplication by $2$ while the map $Q\to C$ is the identity. 

Then a lift amounts to a map $P\to C$ (so $\mathbb{Z\to Z}$) such that $Q\to P\to C = Q\to C$, so a map $\mathbb{Z\to Z}$ such that $\mathbb{Z\overset{2}\to Z\to Z} = id_{\mathbb Z}$. That's of course impossible. 

The condition that you're missing is that $P/Q$ must also be a complex of projectives (or, equivalently here, $Q$ must be a summand of $P$)

If you add this condition then it becomes true.

Comment: Thank you, in my case I have a complex of projectives (let's say) $K$ and $Q:=K\oplus K,P:=\operatorname{cyl} K$, so it should be fine. But still, why does the enriched statement hold?

Comment: Well if you write $P = Q\oplus D$, you only have to define the dotted arrow on $D$, because it is completely determined on $Q$. But then any map $D\to C$ that lifts $D\to A[0]$ will work, because the lower triangle "doesn't take $D$ into account". So you're reduced to "I have a map $D\to A[0]$, can I lift it to $D\to C$ ?". That should be quite easier, can you try that ?